# Repeat issue with UITableView cells

Tags: xcode, uitableview, xcode4

I am fully aware there are many cases of this issue here, although I am stumped and cannot resolve this on my own. I only want to display 4 cells total in my `myTableView2` `UITableView`, but what I am finding is that my cells are being reused no doubt because of this line

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

I understand if I remove the `if(!cell)` line I might disable the `UITableView` from creating new cells, but that doesn't work because it mandates cell creation. Any thoughts? I have posted my code below.

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

 if (!cell)
 {
    NSLog(@"CREATING NEW CELL");
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.contentView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = YES;
 }
 if (tableView == self.myTableView)
 {
  if ([[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
  {        
    cell.textLabel.text = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringValue];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
  }
  else
  {        
    cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
  }
 }
 if (tableView == self.myTableView2)
 {
    self.myTableView2.opaque = NO;
    self.myTableView2.backgroundColor =  [UIColor colorWithRed:(0.0/255.0) green:(0.0/255.0) blue:(102.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];
    self.myTableView2.backgroundView  = nil;

    if ([[array2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [[array2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringValue];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        [cell.textLabel sizeToFit];
        cell.textLabel.font = [self fontForCell];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [array2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        [cell.textLabel sizeToFit];
        cell.textLabel.font = [self fontForCell];
    }
 }
 return cell;
}
```

Other pertinent data:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
 if (tableView==self.myTableView)
 {
    return [array count];
 }
 else if(tableView==self.myTableView2)
 {
    return [array2 count];
 }
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
 if (tableView==self.myTableView)
 {
    return [array count];
 }
 else if(tableView==self.myTableView2)
 {
    return [array2 count];
 }
}
```

Comment: What behavior are you currently seeing and what are you expecting to happen instead?

Comment: Did you link the CellIdentifier name on the storyboard?

Comment: Currently all my data -- which consists of 3 cells total -- is repeating over and over.

Comment: Cell identifier name? No... I only tagged myTableView2 on the storyboard to File's owner, and I have the datasource and delegate set to "self" programmatically.

Comment: My app shows Yelp consumer reviews, and so it's displaying the same reviews countless times, over and over...

Comment: have you verified that the problem is with the tableview and not the array? if you inspect the array does it contain unique values for each entry?

Comment: Sorry to run you guys through it all. I see now my array is the problem. The values repeat constantly for `array2` which is the one I am focused on. Clearly now I need to see why my array is repeating. Thank you!

Comment: your section count a row count methods look wrong too. you can't return twice like that..you'll need something like if (tableview==table1) {return [array count]} else if(tableview==table2) {return [array2 count]}

Comment: Good to know. I thought that was acceptable (novice programmer here) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

Problem #1: the `NSDictionary` "for" loop was unnecessary and was contributing to multiple entries. I erased the loop.

Problem #2: `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `numberOfRowsInSection`. Edited version below. Lesson learned: you want `numberOfSectionsInTableView` to reflect 1 if you only want one instance of your array shown. A value of 2 will cause two instances to be shown, so on and so forth.

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
 if (tableView==self.myTableView)
 {
    return [array count];
 }
 else if(tableView==self.myTableView2)
 {
    return 1;
 }
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
 if (tableView==self.myTableView)
 {
    return 5;
 }
 else if(tableView==self.myTableView2)
 {
    return [array2 count];
 }
}
```